# Получаю ошибку Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

Сам код :

```
var person = {
    name: "Nikita",
    age : 18,
    gender : "male"
}


Object.defineProperty(person, 'age', {
    get : function  () {
        return this.age;
    },
    set : function  (nage) {
        return this.age = nage;
    }
});

console.log(person.age)
person.age = 19;
console.log(person.age)
```

Answer (score 2):

@Grommash The Hellscream функции свойства не должны оперировать самим свойством иначе бесконечная рекурсия Object.defineProperty(person, `'age'`, { изменить имя тут или использовать только value вместо set и get, что особого смысла не имеет, оно уже имеет значение или в самих set и get не использовать `this.age`

Comment: я понимаю,просто хотел сам написать
так где именно изменить имя?в аргументе?на _age?

Comment: @GrommashTheHellscream можно провести аналогию с `C#` https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w86s7x04.aspx   ... там есть поля и свойства. Поля пишутся с заглавной буквы. и через сеттеры и геттеры можно установить свойства. Так вот в вашем случае да, можно заменить имя `age` и например сделать его `Age` как свойство ... и писать при обращении `person.Age`

Comment: @GrommashTheHellscream то есть достаточно написать вот тут `Object.defineProperty(person, 'Age', {`